# How to call methods in Firebase Cloud Messaging integration with Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate `Firebase` Cloud Messaging into my Android Studio project. I began by going to tools, clicking `Firebase`, going to Cloud Messaging, and then clicking "Connect your app to `Firebase`" and "Add `FCM` to your App". Both processes went without a hitch, but the problem came up later. When I was following step 3, there were two blocks of code that we were supposed to integrate. The first block was supposed to be a service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService`. The second block was a dependency that was supposed to be placed in the manifest. These are the two blocks respectively:

The problem is that the service file is returning the error `"Cannot resolve method 'scheduleJob()'", 'handleNow()', and 'sendRegistrationToServer(token)'`

I suspected that new methods had to be created, but these methods were supposed to draw from the parent class (I think). I have not clicked the suggestion to create the new methods because I was uncertain whether there would be any functionality. 
The first set of code below is the file I made by doing

```
File->New->Service->Service.
```

I named the file "MyFirebaseMessagingService". The second set of code is my manifest.

```
package com.example.piggybank_v3;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be:
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }


    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"></service>
<service android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The ideal result is that the project should sync when running, but it returns these errors: `"Cannot resolve method 'scheduleJob()'", 'handleNow()', and 'sendRegistrationToServer(token)'`

Answer (score 0):

This is how service class work to receive notification message. So you've to edit your event in it then it'll works fine.
Firebase cloud message demo's are provided on github so can download it and can change firebase keys and package name to test it.

```
    import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.R;

import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;


public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";


    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
                scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]


    // [START on_new_token]

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }
    // [END on_new_token]

    /**
     * Schedule async work using WorkManager.
     */
    private void scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        OneTimeWorkRequest work = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().beginWith(work).enqueue();
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.- Verify that the library is added in *build.gradle*:

> implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-messaging: 19.0.1'

2.- As indicated, you must add the '*MyFirebaseMessagingService*' service (previously created) to the *AndroidManifest.xml* and provide a default notification channel: ([click here to learn more about the channels](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels))

```
<service
    android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

3.- Add the following in *MainActivity.java* to retrieve the current token when you need it:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                return;
            }

            // Get new Instance ID token
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

4.- Fill in the file *'MyFirebaseMessagingService.java'*:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        // Check if message contains a data payload (beauty messages).
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            createAndSendNotificationB(remoteMessage);      
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload (from console).
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            createAndSendNotificationC(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    private void createAndSendNotificationB(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
            //Code here
    }

    private void createAndSendNotificationC(String messageBody){
            //Code here
    }
}
```

With this it should work.
I have taken everything from the official documentation, I recommend you read it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client